# Read a field from js file in view.html file in Angular JS 1.6

Tags: c#, angularjs, user-interface

Could sound simple to anyone who have used angular js 1.6. I am a beginner who needs to use ng-if tag on my view.html page to show hide a div based on a flag I receive from web api end in angular js 1.6.

The web api is developed using dot net framework and the frontend is using angular 1.6.
My tags are like:

```
 <div class="form-group" ng-if="IsMyFlag == true">

                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <select class="form-control" ng-model="abcid" ng-options="xyz.SessionTypeId as xyz.SessionTypeName for xyz in xyzList" ng-disabled="IsFlgDisabled"></select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

Now here IsMyFlag is declared in the js file for the same view and it is also declared in the model at C# end.

Can someone help me out by telling how to read this IsMyFlag value in the if condition? Please?

Comment: Your view looks correct, is the problem the value `IsMyFlag` not set? Have you got the controller set to this view, and is `IsMyFlag` in that controller?

Comment: You should show controller code also

Comment: Hey guys, thank you for your time. I was struggling for last 8 hours and finally got it as soon as I posted it here.
Thanks. I will post it as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this question, basically we need to set the property in the .js page if we want to use any property in the .view page in angularjs 1.6. 
For setting the value, you need to assign it in .js file as 
$scope.IsMyFlag = data.IsMyFlag; 
where the data object contains the model value from the backend code/api code.

Thanks for your responses.